# Cant figure out this error -> IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

So i have been working on this code for a while and i cant fin a solution to this problem and i was wondering if anyone in here could help me solve this? The problem is supposed to be in the method "hent_celle" where it takes in a coordinate from a grid and returns the object that is in that position.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/cc/Documents/Python/Oblig8/rutenettto.py", line 105, in <module> 
    print(testobjekt._sett_naboer(2,1)) 
File "/Users/cc/Documents/Python/Oblig8/rutenettto.py", line 64, in 
    _sett_naboer nabo_u_kol = self.hent_celle(rad+1,kol) 
File "/Users/cc/Documents/Python/Oblig8/rutenettto.py", line 43, in hent_celle 
    return self._rutenett[rad][kol] IndexError: list index out of range
```

And the code is:

```
from random import randint 
from celle import Celle

class Rutenett: 
def init(self,rader,kolonner): 
    self._ant_rader = int(rader) 
    self._ant_kolonner = int(kolonner) self._rutenett = []

def _lag_tom_rad(self):
    liste = []
    for x in range(self._ant_kolonner):
        liste.append(None)
    return liste

def _lag_tomt_rutenett(self):
    liste2 = []
    for x in range(self._ant_rader):
        liste_ = self._lag_tom_rad()
        liste2.append(liste_)
    self._rutenett = liste2

def lag_celle(self,rad,kol):
    celle = Celle()
    tilfeldig_tall = randint(0,100)
    if tilfeldig_tall <= 33:
        celle.sett_levende()
        return celle
    else:
        return celle

def fyll_med_tilfeldige_celler(self):
    for x in self._rutenett:
        for y in x:
            rad = int(self._rutenett.index(x))
            kol = int(x.index(y))
            self._rutenett[rad][kol] = self.lag_celle(rad,kol)

def hent_celle(self,rad,kol):
    if rad > self._ant_rader or kol > self._ant_kolonner or rad < 0 or kol < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return self._rutenett[rad][kol]

def tegn_rutenett(self):
    for x in self._rutenett:
        for y in x:
            print(y.hent_status_tegn(), end="")


def hent_alle_celler(self):
    liste = []
    for x in self._rutenett:
        for y in x:
            liste.append(y)
    return liste

def _sett_naboer(self,rad,kol):
    cellen = self.hent_celle(rad,kol)
    # lik linje
    nabo_v_rad = self.hent_celle(rad,kol-1)
    nabo_h_rad = self.hent_celle(rad,kol+1)
    # under
    nabo_u_kol = self.hent_celle(rad+1,kol)
    nabo_u_kol_h = self.hent_celle(rad+1,kol+1)
    nabo_u_kol_v = self.hent_celle(rad+1,kol-1)
    # over
    nabo_o_kol = self.hent_celle(rad-1,kol)
    nabo_o_kol_h = self.hent_celle(rad-1,kol+1)
    nabo_o_kol_v = self.hent_celle(rad-1,kol-1)

    liste = [nabo_v_rad,nabo_h_rad,nabo_u_kol_h,nabo_u_kol_v,nabo_o_kol,nabo_o_kol_h,nabo_o_kol_v]
    #print(liste)
    #print(nabo_o_kol_h)
    
    for x in liste:
        if x == None:
            pass
        else:
            cellen._naboer.append(x)
    return cellen._naboer
    

def antall_levende(self):
    teller = 0
    for x in self._rutenett:
        for y in x:
            if y._status == "doed":
                pass
            else:
                teller +=1
    return teller

testobjekt = Rutenett(3,3) 
testobjekt._lag_tomt_rutenett() 
testobjekt.fyll_med_tilfeldige_celler() 
print(testobjekt._sett_naboer(2,1))
```

I just cant figure out why the list index is out of range

Comment: This is far from a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Pyhton list indexes start at 0, which means a list with 10 elements will use indices 0-9. Assuming `self._ant_rader` and `self._ant_kolonner` are the number of rows and columns, then `rad` and `kol` would need to be *less than* those values and cannot be the same value, or you get an index out of bounds error.

Fixed version of the method:

```py
def hent_celle(self,rad,kol):
    if rad >= self._ant_rader or kol >= self._ant_kolonner or rad < 0 or kol < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return self._rutenett[rad][kol]
```

As you can see, the `>` has been replaced with `>=` instead. This means indices which are out of bounds will return `None`.